# Unable to select radio button option for multiple questions

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I have run into a problem related to radio buttons.
The issue is that I have around 7 questions and each question has 2 options of radio button in 2 columns.
So if I select an option for the first question, and then want to select the option for 2nd question. The selected radio buttons disappear from the first question and appear on the 2nd one.
The issue is that I can not select more than one question.

Here is the code

```html
<td colspan="4" style="align-items: center;">
  <div class="form-group m-0 m-b-15">
    <div class="radio mt-radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="q1"  id="q_1_w" >
      <label for="q_1_w" >Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1"  id="q_1_x">
      <label for="q_1_x" style="margin-left: 30px;">No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td colspan="6">
  <div class="form-group m-0 m-b-15">
    <div class="radio mt-radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q_1_y" >
      <label for="q_1_y" >Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q_1_z">
      <label for="q_1_z" style="margin-left: 30px;">No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: each radio group must have differents values, + you don't need id for radio buttons

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is because you gave the same name for all the radio buttons, try giving different names. For example :-

Try using name="q2" for the second one.

```
    <div class="form-group m-0 m-b-15">
     <div class="radio mt-radio-inline">
     <input type="radio" name="q2"  id="q_1_y" ><label for="q_1_y" >Yes</label>
     <input type="radio" name="q2"  id="q_1_z"><label for="q_1_z" style="margin-left: 30px;">No</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

myForm.onsubmit = evt =>
  {
  evt.preventDefault() // disable submit
  
  console.clear()
  console.log('q1 =', myForm.q1.value )
  console.log('q2 =', myForm.q2.value )
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
  <h5> Question 1 </h5>

  <label> <input type="radio" name="q1" value="yes"> Yes </label>
  <label> <input type="radio" name="q1" value="no"> No </label>

  
  <h5> Question 2 </h5>

  <label> <input type="radio" name="q2" value="yes"> Yes </label>
  <label> <input type="radio" name="q2" value="no"> No </label>

  <hr>
  <button type="submit"> read values </button>
</form>
```